# Creating CSS from a HTML file

Tags: java, html, css

I have an html file which contains many elements:

```html
<div>
    <div id="imgElt11289447233738dIi15v" style="BORDER-RIGHT: 0px; BORDER-TOP: 0px; Z-INDEX: 1; LEFT: 795px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 90px; CURSOR: auto; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 186px; HEIGHT: 93px" lineid="lineid" y2="279" y1="186" x2="885" x1="795">
        <img style="WIDTH: 90px; HEIGHT: 93px" height="21" alt="Image" src="../images//k03.jpg" width="25" name="imgElt11289447233738dIi15vNI1m6G" tag="img"></img></div>
    <div id="imgElt11288263284216dIi15v" style="BORDER-RIGHT: 0px; BORDER-TOP: 0px; Z-INDEX: 1; LEFT: 660px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 147px; CURSOR: auto; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 1964px; HEIGHT: 22px" lineid="lineid" y2="1986" y1="1964" x2="807" x1="660">
        <img style="WIDTH: 147px; HEIGHT: 22px" height="21" alt="Image" src="../images//k03.jpg" width="25" name="imgElt11288263284216dIi15vNI1m6G" tag="img"></img></div>
    <div id="txtElt11288262779851dIi15v" style="BORDER-RIGHT: 0px; BORDER-TOP: 0px; Z-INDEX: 2872735; LEFT: 250px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 95px; CURSOR: auto; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 1514px; HEIGHT: 18px" selectedindex="0" pos_rel="false" lineid="lineid" y2="1532" y1="1514" x2="345" x1="250" tag="div">
        <p><strong><font face="arial,helvetica,sans-serif" size="2">Course Name</font></strong></p>
    </div>
    <div id="txtElt11288262309675dIi15v" style="BORDER-RIGHT: 0px; BORDER-TOP: 0px; Z-INDEX: 1565881; LEFT: 40px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 430px; CURSOR: auto; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 1464px; HEIGHT: 34px" selectedindex="0" pos_rel="false" lineid="lineid" y2="1498" y1="1464" x2="470" x1="40" tag="div">
        <p><strong>
        <font face="arial,helvetica,sans-serif" size="2" tag="font">16. Please 
        write below the Course Name in order of preference.</font></strong></p>
        <p tag="p"><strong><font face="Arial" size="2" tag="font">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; (Please 
        see the &quot;Instructions to Candidate&quot; for list of courses)</font></strong></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

As can be seen, 1 div has many divs in it. Now I want to create a css file that will contain all the styling of this html page (need not be same). Have to write something in java code. I have the DOM object of this file available to me.

Basically, I want all the styles to be removed from here and will be kept under a CSS file like for div with id = imgElt11289447233738dIi15v css will be:

```css
#imgElt11289447233738dIi15v{BORDER-RIGHT: 0px; BORDER-TOP: 0px; Z-INDEX: 1; LEFT: 795px; BORDER-LEFT: 0px; WIDTH: 90px; CURSOR: auto; BORDER-BOTTOM: 0px; POSITION: absolute; TOP: 186px; HEIGHT: 93px}
```

I am don't till this part but since I don't know how many levels of hierarchy of elements will be there is there any way to do the same for all child elements as well?

I used the following code

```
public static Document getStyleInCSSfile(Document aoDoc, String aoPathToWrite, String aoFileName) throws ApplicationException {
    String loValue = null;
    String loID = null;
    String lsContent = "";
    Element loRoot = aoDoc.getRootElement();
    List loTempElementList = loRoot.getChildren();
    int liCounter;
    for (liCounter = 0; liCounter < loTempElementList.size(); liCounter++) {
        Element loTemplateEle = (Element) loTempElementList.get(liCounter);
        String loId=loTemplateEle.getAttribute("id").getValue();
        loID = loTemplateEle.getAttributeValue("id");
        if(null != loID)
        {
            loValue = loTemplateEle.getAttributeValue("style");
            if(loValue!=null && loValue.trim().length()>0)
            {
                loTemplateEle.removeAttribute("style");
                lsContent = lsContent.concat("#"+loID+"{"+loValue+"}\n");
            }
        }
    }
    SaveFormOnLocalUtil.writeToFile(aoPathToWrite,aoFileName,lsContent);
    return aoDoc;
}
```

**Edit :** got to know that some regular expression may help by getting a string of SAX parser object and and using regular expression on it... any idea? any one? how to implement it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use SAX instead of DOM. In SAX you can register the handler that is called every time the parser sees new tag, attribute etc. In this case every time you see attribute "style" you should extract its value to CSS file.

The next approach is using Digester from jakarta.apache.org. It uses SAX and allows XML configuration (see DigesterDigester) that maps your value object directly yo your XML document.

Absolutely different solution may made using unix shell commands like grep and sed. The preference to one of the solution depends on your system requirements and how often do you have to run this code. If it is one time transformation use unix shell scripting. If it must be something robust and change the pages on the fly use java solution.

Comment: i used SAX parser for reading dom. but couldnt find how to traverse through each element of the tree structure that will be created

Comment: done Using SAX parser created a recursive function based  on requirements :)

Answer (score 1):

is it effective to define a style for each single tag?

if i were you i'd checked if any other tag has the same style and if all elements with one style had the same 'tag_name' i'd used the following:

```
tag_name{text-transform:uppercase;text-align:center;}
```

and every element with this tag name (if its' style isn't set in any other way) would have this style.
if there's a lot of different tags with the same style:

```
.class_name{text-transform:uppercase;text-align:center;}
```

`<tag class="class_name">content</tag>`